# не работают кнопки <a id=""> если рядом находится <div>

Tags: javascript, html, button

если вторая ячейка пуста - при нажатии первой id="clear" срабатывает и вызывает функцию
а если во второй ячейке любой   - ничего не работает
как это исправить?

```js
clear.addEventListener('click', doCanvas);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="buttond" style="text-align:center;"><a id="clear" target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:19px;  text-decoration: none; padding:10px 20px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#0095ff; border-radius:5px; border: 0px solid #0095ff;">очистить</a>
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; width: 130px; height: 25px;   padding:10px 20px; background-color:#0095ff; border-radius:5px; border: 0px solid #0095ff;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: вот в том коде, который вы написали - "вторая ячейка" пустая, или непустая?

Comment: и второй вопрос - как вы определяете, что функция НЕ вызываестя? вдруг она вызывается, но не делает то, что надо? алертом проверяли?

Comment: не пустая, таблица из двух ячеек
она вообще ничего не делает, ни ошибки ни алерт